# How can I make a bot add different roles on different reactions?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Currently, the bot only listens to a single reaction. If I add another reaction, it won't trigger.

```js
bot.once('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  if(message.channel.id === "740513426631163945") {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === "\uD83C\uDDE7") {
      member.addRole("741434891157110795");
    }
    else if (reaction.emoji.name === "\uD83C\uDDF4") {
      member.addRole("741435543723835484");
    }
  }
});
```

I am using Discord.js v11.

Comment: what do you mean by "bot only listens to single reaction"

Comment: I have removed the *bot won't listen to old messages* part, as that should be a new question following on from this one.

Comment: Also, do you want the roles to be added when a user reacts to any message or specific messages?

Comment: @Daemon Beast actually specific message.

Comment: @Levi_OP you can see I added if and else if for 2 reactions. But the bot will only listen to the first reaction. If I send another message I can add the other reaction but only 1 per message.

Comment: @Hafalar436 Please add the code you use for sending a message.

Comment: @DaemonBeast I don't send messages. I made the message myself and want the bot to permanently watch that message.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a command called `!follow` that allows you to add the *role on reaction* functionality to a message that you have already sent.

When a reaction is added to a message, a check is done to see if the message is being tracked, and another check is done to see if the added reaction is one you want to track (if not, it is deleted). The member that added the reaction is then found and a certain role is added depending on the reaction they chose.

```js
const prefix = '!';

const polls = new Discord.Collection();

bot.on('message', message => {
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/\s+/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  switch (command) {
    case 'follow':
      if (!args[0]) return message.reply(`Please provide the ID of the message.\n**Usage:** \`${prefix}follow\``);
      
      const msg = message.channel.messages.get(args[0]);
      if (!msg) return message.reply('Could not find the specified message.');

      message.delete();

      polls.set(msg.id, true);
    default:
      message.reply(`The command \`${command}\` was not recognized.`);
  }
});

bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  if (!polls.has(reaction.message.id)) return;
  if (!['', ''].includes(message.reaction.name)) return reaction.remove();

  const member = reaction.message.channel.members.find(member => member.id === user.id);

  switch (message.reaction.name) {
    case '':
      member.addRole('741434891157110795');
      break;
    case '':
      member.addRole('741435543723835484');
      break;
});
```